# Можно ли в интерфейсах создавать виртуальные и статические методы?

Tags: c#, методы, интерфейс

Можно ли в интерфейсах создавать виртуальные, статические, абстрактные методы?

Comment: В интерфейсах можно определять реализацию метода по умолчанию, по сути это можно рассматривать как виртуальный метод. Но вот статические методы - вряд ли (по крайней мере, я не знаю о такой возможности)

Comment: [interface (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface). C# 11 привнёс много нового.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov теперь по факту это класс)) Такой бред вообще)

Comment: Если не брать во внимание новинки, то все методы интерфейса виртуальные по умолчанию. А зачем нужны статические - для меня загадка. Как бы майкрософт не извращался, синглтоны он всё равно не заменит.

Comment: @aepot, так это же не про синглтоны, а про перегрузку операторов. Раньше не было возможности имплементатора класса заставить добавлять методы для операторов, сейчас же объявил в интерфейсе абстрактный и вуаля. Это продолжение истории с операторами мат. действий над дженериками, как я понимаю. Нет?